# Minipages with "fixed" sizes, completely break alignment when content is added to them

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, subfloats, minipage

The following example run through `pdflatex`, with an `fbox` that simply surrounds each minipage which I have omitted for clarity:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    \subcaption{A}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    \subcaption{B}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    \subcaption{C}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{My figures}
\end{figure}
```

produces a rather nice side-by-side collection of minipages, like:

[image]

However, when I add something to these minipages, for example:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    \subcaption{A}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    Text, or a graph, or a table, or whatever goes here
    \subcaption{B}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.15\textheight][t]{0.28\textwidth}
    % define the graphic in a way that ensures it does not exceed the minipage boundary
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{my-graph.pdf}
    \subcaption{C}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{My figures}
\end{figure}
```

everything stops being so nice, and results in:

[image]

Why does this happen? I would assume that the content of a fixed-size minipage is totally independent from the content of other fixed-size minipages, but this is not the case? How can I make it behave sensibly and keep the minipages fixed as I have defined them? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are aligning the minipages with [t] and so along the baseline of the first line of their content. Add \vspace{0pt} as first command to all minipages and the baseline will be at the top for all of them.

Comment: That works! I think I misunderstood [t] as something more  of a global horizontal line, rather than a relative thing. Thanks so much!